# On spectrum of a linear operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $S,T$ bounded linear operators defined on $H$. I am interested in showing that:

1. If $S,T$ are self-adjoint operators with compact $S$ and $ST=TS$ then $$\sigma(T+S)\subset \sigma(T)\cup \sigma_p(T+S).$$

Here $\sigma(T)$ denotes the spectrum of $T$ defined by:
$$\sigma(T)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C} : T-\lambda I\hspace{.2cm}\mbox{it is not invertible}\}.$$
and $\sigma_p(T)$ is the set of eigenvalues of $T$.

*Any contribution will be appreciated. Greetings!!*

Comment: A hint: $\sigma_p(T+S) \subset \sigma(T + S)$, so try to investigate the situation where $T + S - \lambda I$ is not invertible, but $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

As written, this is not true. Let $H=L^2[0,1]\oplus L^2[2,3]$. Let $f$ be the identity function $f(t)=t$, and
$$
T=M_f\oplus 0,\qquad S= 0\oplus M_f, 
$$
where $M_f$ is the multiplication operator.
Then $T+S=M_f\oplus M_f$ has no eigenvalues, so the claimed inclusion becomes $\sigma(S+T)\subset\sigma(T)$. But
$$
\sigma(S+T)=[0,1]\cup[2,3],
$$
while
$$
\sigma(T)=[0,1]. 
$$